# How Can I Create a Deep Link to Tab from simple text Notification in Activity Feed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send an Activity Feed notification that links to a custom Apps tab. I've seen related posts of people doing this with an "attachment card". But I'd like to do it with a text nofitication.

I've tried formatting the notification's preview text, setting the Content Type to HTML like so:

```
var previewText = new ItemBody
                    {
                        Content = "<HTML CONTENT>",
                        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    };
```

But got the following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Content
> Type 'Html' is not supported

I'm sending the notification like this:

```
await GraphClient.Users[userId].Teamwork
                            .SendActivityNotification(topic, activity-type, null,
                             previewText, templateParameters)
                            .Request()
                            .PostAsync();
```

Is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to redirect to the application with the following topic:

```
var topic = new TeamworkActivityTopic
                {
                    Source = TeamworkActivityTopicSource.EntityUrl,
                    Value = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{Teams App ID}"
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, so it might not work, but if you can send text in the notification it might support Team's markdown subset, which includes the ability to send a link. See here for more: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

In the link you could use a deeplink to the app tab.